# PGFPlots: Mathematical expressions

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

## Question

Is there a way to include mathematical expressions in PGFPlots, for example, `[domain=1/3:e^5/3]`?

PGFPlots is fairly useful, however the ability to put mathematical expressions directly into Tikz makes life much easier.

The only way around this problem that I know of is to define a bunch of constants above the before entering the `axis environment`. I find this a little obnoxious.

[image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=1/3:e^5/3,x=0.1cm, scale=1]

    % Axes
    \draw[help lines]   (-0.2 cm,0) -- (e^5/3+0.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[help lines]   (0,-0.2) -- (0,6) node[above] {$y$};
    \draw[gray, thick]  (e^5/3,5) -- (-0.075/0.1,5) node[left] {$y=5$};
    \draw[gray, thick]  (e^5/3,4) -- (-0.075/0.1,4) node[left] {$y=4$};

    % Curves
    \draw[blue, thick] plot[id=lnx] (\x,{ln(3*\x)}) node[right] {$\ln 3x$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can directly write `\addplot[domain=1/3:e^5/3] {ln(3*x)}` in `pgfplots`: it applies the math parser. That said, there are still lots of places where the math parser should be invoked... a relic of times when the floating point unit was unavailable.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: It seems like this doesn't work when the axis is logarithmic. `xmode=log,domain=1/3:e^5/3` leads to `Could not parse input '1/3' as a floating point number`. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Yes, that works for the domain. However, try to write `\begin{semilogyaxis}[xmin=-1, xmax=e^5/3+5,] ...` and you'll run into issues! This is likely one of those places where the math parser could stretch its legs a little.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Anyhow, pgfplots is so useful that I am using  it, albeit with tons and tons of `\pgfmathsetmacro` expressions. Hehehe

Comment: @Jake and JDG: I fear these are two of the places were I should really apply the math parser... I will take a note.

Comment: Your name is very familiar and you're talking as if you wrote `pgfplots`...and after looking you up, that is precisely who you are. I'm amazed by the work you've done. And yes, please apply the math parser as much as possible. By the way, I was happy to find that Euler's constant e works. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Jake Good point.

Comment: @Jake and JDG: the next stable version will come with support for the math parser in axis limits and log domains (already committed to git repo).

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger That is great news. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a slightly modified version of the `domain` key to save yourself the trouble of manually parsing the expressions first. If you include the following snippet in your document, you'll be able to type `domain*=1/3:e^5/3` even when you're using logarithmic axes (and similarly for `xmin`, `ymax`, etc.):

```
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    domain*/.code args={#1:#2}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplots@lower{#1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplots@upper{#2}
        \pgfplotsset{domain=\pgfplots@lower:\pgfplots@upper}
    },
    xmin*/.code={
        \pgfmathparse{#1}
        \pgfplotsset{xmin=\pgfmathresult}
    },
    xmax*/.code={
        \pgfmathparse{#1}
        \pgfplotsset{xmax=\pgfmathresult}
    },  
    ymin*/.code={
        \pgfmathparse{#1}
        \pgfplotsset{ymin=\pgfmathresult}
    },
    ymax*/.code={
        \pgfmathparse{#1}
        \pgfplotsset{ymax=\pgfmathresult}
    }
}
\makeatother
```

Your plot could be implemented in PGFPlots using something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    domain*/.code args={#1:#2}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplots@lower{#1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplots@upper{#2}
        \pgfplotsset{domain=\pgfplots@lower:\pgfplots@upper}
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmode=log,
    log ticks with fixed point,
    axis lines*=left,
    xlabel=$x$,
    every axis x label/.style={
        at={(rel axis cs:1,0)},
        anchor=west
    },
    ylabel=$y$,
    every axis y label/.style={
        at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},
        anchor=south
    },
    ymin=0,
    xmin=0.1,
    enlarge x limits=false,
    domain*=1/3:e^5/3,
    ytick={0,4,5},
    ymajorgrids,
    yticklabel={$y = \pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$},
    clip=false
]
\addplot [thick, red] {ln(3*x)} node [anchor=west] {$\ln 3x$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a great piece of code. However, I tried out the solution and it works in some cases, but does not work in others. For example, I received an error when typing `xmin=1/3`. In that case, one would still need to make use of commands like `\pgfmathsetmacro`.

Comment: @JDG: Well, it only works as a replacement for the `domain` key, of course. It doesn't do anything to `xmin`, or `ymax`, etc. You can define similar code snippets for those: `\pgfplotsset{xmin*/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1}\pgfplotsset{xmin=\pgfmathresult}}` and then use `xmin*=1/3` instead of `xmin=1/3`. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Pgfplot Workaround

As an answer, here's the Pgfplot workaround I mentioned, which defines variables using `\pgfmathsetmacro` before the `axis environment`. The advantage of this workaround is that it is extremely easy to understand and can be reused easily for similar graphs, which is useful for Calculus 1–3-level homework problems.

[image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]

\pgfmathsetmacro\xDomainMin{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xDomainMax{e^5/3*3}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xMin{-10}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xMax{\xDomainMax+\xDomainMax/50}
\pgfmathsetmacro\yMin{-1}
\pgfmathsetmacro\yMax{6}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xRotation{(e^5/3+5)/2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\yRotation{0}

\begin{semilogyaxis}[    
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center,
    axis z line=center,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    zlabel={$z$},
    axis line style=help lines,
    gray,
    every axis/.append style={font=\tiny},
    width=10cm,
    height=8cm,
    domain=\xDomainMin:\xDomainMax,
    xmin=\xMin, xmax=\xMax,
    ymin=\yMin, ymax=\yMax,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick={4,5},
    yticklabels={$y=4$,$y=5$},
    area style,
]
    \addplot[id=five, gray, very thin, fill=blue, opacity=0.1] {5} \closedcycle;
    \addplot[id=lnx, white, very thin, mark=none, samples=200, fill=white,]
        {ln(3*x)}\closedcycle;
    \addplot[id=four, gray, very thin, fill=white] {4} \closedcycle;
    \addplot[id=five, gray, very thin,] {5};
    \addplot[id=five, white, very thin, fill=white,
            domain=\xDomainMax-0.1:\xDomainMax+1] {5} \closedcycle;
\addplot[id=lnx, blue, very thin, mark=none, samples=200,]
        {ln(3*x)} node [right]{\color{blue}$\ln x$};

\draw[->,gray, thick]
    (axis cs:6,4.5) arc (-30:-150:8 pt);


\end{semilogyaxis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```